# Refresh datasource dynamically in kendo mvvm

Tags: data-binding, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Hi I've a kendo grid with country and state details. And I've a toolbar with add button. When I click on add new button, I'm getting a popup with country and state dropdowns. Now I want to select country then state. But here I want to load states based on country selection. Here is my sample code. It is not working.

```
function loadStates(element) {

// here I want to update below model
StateModel.StatesByCountry

something like this.
        StateModel.LoadStatesByCountry($(element).val(), function () {

        });

    }

    <script id="popup_editor" type="text/x-kendo-template">
         <div class="k-edit-label">
                        <label for="Country">Country</label>
                    </div>


                    <input name="CntryName" 
                        data-bind="value:CntryName"
                        data-value-field="Value" 
                        data-text-field="Text" 
                        data-source= CountryModel.AllCountries
                        data-role="dropdownlist"
                        onChange="loadStates(this)"
                 />


        <div class="k-edit-label">
                        <label for="State">State</label>
                    </div>
                    <input name="StateName" 
                        data-bind="value:StateName" 
                        data-value-field="StateID" 
                        data-text-field="StateName" 
                        data-source=StateModel.StatesByCountry 
                        data-role="dropdownlist"     />
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Every time you have a country selected, you can filter the states available, so you don't have to care about it in the next popup.

See examples here http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#methods-filter

Comment: in that case we have to load all states at a time then filter based on country selection?

Comment: Yeah, you will only lload them once, and change which ones are 'visible' every time

Comment: but that will reduce some performance I think. So I wanted to load based on country selection only.

Comment: I think it would be better to load all states in one call, than making a call every time the user selects a country, to load just a few words.